# RHEL 7: Obtaining Extended Reboot History

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

Other than **last reboot**, how may I obtain the reboot history of a RHEL 7 host? **last reboot** is providing only two weeks of history. I need to go back much further.

For example, may **ausearch** be used? If so, I am unsure what specific syntax to use.

Are there other techniques I may use?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using `logrotate`  to rotate the `wtmp` file?

Comment: Yes, but only one old version of wtmp is kept, which bought me only a couple of more weeks.

Comment: Then you are almost certainly out of luck.

Comment: 'fraid that was the case. Thank you for chiming in, appreciated!